# DatePicker to only show the calendar (i.e.: no header)

Tags: android, datepicker

With the new Datepicker widget, it shows a header with a large amount of wasted space.
Is it possible to only show the calendar part without the header?

[image: datetimepicker]

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the CalendarView, which does not show the header.

Comment: Good find. Will consider this option in the future.